# How to make the function key F5 to function by clicking a button?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

My computer <kbd>F5</kbd> function key is broken. I need to refresh data every day. Thus I plan to design a windows form with one button. If I click that button, it would need to perform as <kbd>F5</kbd> key.

The below code is shows were I design. But it does not work.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Select Case Keys.F5
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the `Select Case` in this, well, case.

```
My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys(CStr(Keys.F5))
```

would be all you really need. You'd just slap this into your `Sub`. Lemme know if this fixes your issue!